# Finding Numbers where modulo is k

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I have given a number $A$ where $1\le A\le 10^6$ and a number $K$. I have to find the all the numbers between $1$ to $A$ where $A\%i=k$ and $i$ is $1\le i\le A$. Is there any better solution than looping?

Simple Solution Would be

```
for(int i=1;i<=A;i++)
   if(A%i==k) count++;
```

Is there any better solution than iterating all the numbers between $1$ to $A$?

Answer (score 2):

If $A \equiv k \pmod n$, then $n \mid A - k$. Thus if you find all factors of $A - k$, you will find all $n$ such that $A \equiv k \pmod n$. Further, we require that $k < n$ if it is a remainder, so there is your answer.